# How to pass parameters when there's no table columns (GeomFromText('Polygon (( ? ?,))) node-maria

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb

I'm looking for a solution How to send parameters for node-maria(mysql) GeomFremText('Polygon (())').

working query

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(LINK_ID) AS LINK_LIST
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LINK_ID FROM SCS_M_LINK WHERE mbrintersects
    (GEOM, 
    GeomFromText
        ('Polygon 
            ((
                36.46830191516196 127.24081993103029,
                36.491973470593685 127.24081993103029,
                36.491973470593685 127.33235836029054,
                36.46830191516196 127.33235836029054,
                36.46830191516196 127.24081993103029
                ))' ))) AS T1;
```

my backend code(query):

```
  `SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(LINK_ID) AS LINK_LIST
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LINK_ID FROM SCS_M_LINK WHERE mbrintersects
(GEOM, 
GeomFromText
    ('Polygon (( ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ?, ? ? ))' ))) AS T1;`
```

related code:

```
  const bindParams = [ parseFloat(southA), parseFloat(westA), 
            parseFloat(northA) , parseFloat(westB), parseFloat(northB), parseFloat(eastA), parseFloat(southB), 
            parseFloat(eastB), parseFloat(southC), parseFloat(westC) ]
 const result = await functions.sendQuery( query, bindParams )
```

These ? <- question mark doesn't work at all.
I think it's becuase I'm missing matching column names, but It's in Polygon, so I do not have a column names...

Could anyone help to send the query..? other queries are working perfect. only this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just surprised by how stupid I am. Didn't think enough. I've mapped them with variable names and works perfect.

```
const bindParams = []
const query = `SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(LINK_ID) AS LINK_LIST
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LINK_ID FROM SCS_M_LINK WHERE mbrintersects
        (GEOM, 
        GeomFromText
            ('Polygon (( ${ southA } ${ westA }, ${ northA } ${ westB }, ${ northB } ${ eastA }, ${ southB } ${ eastB }, ${ southC } ${ westC } ))' ))) AS T1;`
```